# Package Manager Console - Update a specific project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

Quick question regarding the Package Manager Console and the “Update Package” command.

I currently have a single solution hosting two MVC 4.0 projects (one of them is Set as Startup Project).

When I open the `Package Manager Console`, I choose the project I want to update from the `Default project dropdown` and then, I launch the “`Update-Package`” command.

To my surprise, the “`Update-Package`” command does not take into account the project I have selected inside the `Default project dropdown` but instead, it updates both my MVC 4.0 projects.

The workaround is to manually specify my project name inside the “Update-Package” command like so: `Update-Package -ProjectName Kobo.Portal.Web`

Out of curiosity, does anyone know why the Update-Package command does not take into account the selected/targeted project in the Default project dropdown?

Is this a known issue? Is this by design? What’s the purpose of having to choose a Default project if the Package Manager Console won’t take it into account?

Perhaps my understanding of the Package Manager Console is wrong :-(

Thanks in advance for anyone shedding some light on this.

Sincerely
Vince

Answer (score 23):

To update a specific project you can specify

```
Update-Package -ProjectName <yourproject>
```

To get detailed help on the commands in the  Package Management console you can type

```
get-help update-package -detailed
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the –ProjectName parameter as I've mentioned in my post. The question is more if you know *why* the Default project dropdown does not get taken into account? Or more importantly, what’s the purpose behind allowing you to select your project in dropdown? When does it come into play?

Comment: it comes into play to install packages. Install-Package xxx will install in the selected project there. I agree that the behaviour is not very consistent.

Answer (score 2):

to update all existing Nuget packages in 1 project inside your solution. note that in **Package Manager Console** autocomplete works for commands and project name and packages

```
Update-Package -ProjectName Project1 -Reinstall
```